# PHP ignore dollar sign

Tags: php

PHP

```
<?php 
    $a = $offer->service_original_price_display;

    $b = $offer->service_discounted_price_display;

    $c = $a - $b;
?>
```

However I am getting this error: A non-numeric value encountered since service_original_price_display is '$500' and service_discounted_price_display is '$300'. I assume it is because both contains the dollar sign hence PHP is not able to perform the equation. Is there any solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully your never want to handle multiple currencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$a = str_replace("$", "", $offer->service_original_price_display);
$b = str_replace("$", "",$offer->service_discounted_price_display);
```

$ is string

Answer (score 0):

use trim($a, '$'); to remove both side $ sign

Answer (score 0):

You can use substr, if you know the first place is always occupied by a `$` from an error standpoint, removing the `$` ( with str_replace ) is probably better. But, as those answers where already posted.  I get the scraps ( lol ).

```
$a = '$500';

$b = '$300';


$c = substr($a,1) - substr($b,1);

echo $c;
```